# Parsing large txt files in ruby taking a lot of time?

Tags: ruby

below is the code to download a txt file from internet approx 9000 lines and populate the database, I have tried a lot but it takes a lot of time more than 7 minutes. I am using win 7 64 bit and ruby 1.9.3. Is there a way to do it faster ??

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'dbi'
dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:mfmodel:localhost","root","")
#file = open('http://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAV0.txt')
file = File.open('test.txt','r')
lines = file.lines
2.times { lines.next }
curSubType = ''
curType = ''
curCompName = ''
lines.each do |line|
    line.strip!
if line[-1] == ')'
    curType,curSubType = line.split('(')
    curSubType.chop!
elsif line[-4..-1] == 'Fund'
    curCompName = line.split(" Mutual Fund")[0] 
elsif line == ''
    next
else
    sCode,isin_div,isin_re,sName,nav,rePrice,salePrice,date = line.split(';')
    sCode = Integer(sCode)
    sth = dbh.prepare "call mfmodel.populate(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    sth.execute curCompName,curSubType,curType,sCode,isin_div,isin_re,sName
end
end
dbh.do "commit"
dbh.disconnect
file.close


106799;-;-;HDFC ARBITRAGE FUND RETAIL PLAN DIVIDEND OPTION;10.352;10.3;10.352;29-Jun-2012
```

This is the format of data to be inserted in the table. Now there are 8000 such lines and how can I do an insert by combining all that and call the procedure just once. Also, does mysql support arrays and iteration to do such a thing inside the routine. Please give your suggestions.Thanks.

**EDIT**

I have to make insertion's into the tables depending on whether they are already exist or not, also I need to make use of conditional comparison's before inserting into the table. I definitely can't write SQL statements for these, so I wrote SQL stored procedures. Now I have a list @the_data, how do I pass that to the procedure and then iterate through it all on MySQL side. Any ideas ?

```
insert into mfmodel.company_masters (company_name) values
#{@the_data.map {|str| "('#{str[0]}')"}.join(',')}
```

this makes 100 insertions but 35 of them are redundant so I need to search the table for existing entries before doing a insertion.

Any Ideas ? **thanks**

Comment: Comment out all of the lines that connect to the database and store data in it, leaving only the text processing.  How fast is it then?

Comment: @wayne amazing it was instantaneous(almost), but I need to populate the database. Is there a way that OOP can help me, as I am using plain programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your comment, it looks like you are spending all your time executing DB queries. On a recent Ruby project, I also had to optimize some slow code which was importing data from CSV files into the database. I got about a 500x performance increase by importing all the data by using a single bulk `INSERT` query, rather than 1 query for each row of the CSV file. I accumulated all the data in an array, and then built a single SQL query using string interpolation and `Array#join`.

From your comments, it seems that you may not know how to build and execute dynamic SQL for a bulk `INSERT`. First get your data in a nested array, with the fields to be inserted in a known order. Just for an example, imagine we have data like this:

```
some_data = [['106799', 'HDFC FUND'], ['112933', 'SOME OTHER FUND']]
```

You seem to be using Rails and MySQL, so the dynamic SQL will have to use MySQL syntax. To build and execute the `INSERT`, you can do something like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(<<SQL)
  INSERT INTO some_table (a_column, another_column)
  VALUES #{some_data.map { |num,str| "(#{num},'#{str}')" }.join(',')};
SQL
```

You said that you need to insert data into 2 different tables. That's not a problem; just accumulate the data for each table in a different array, and execute 2 dynamic queries, perhaps inside a transaction. 2 queries will be much faster than 9000.

Again, you said in the comments that you may need to *update* some records rather than inserting. That was also the case in the "CSV import" case which I mentioned above. The solution is only slightly more complicated:

```
# sometimes code speaks more eloquently than prose
require 'set'
already_imported = Set.new
MyModel.select("unique_column_which_also_appears_in_imported_files").each do |x|
  already_imported << x.unique_column_which_also_appears_in_imported_files
end

to_insert,to_update = [],[]
imported_data.each do |row|
  # for the following line, don't let different data types 
  #   (like String vs. Numeric) get ya
  # if you need to convert the imported data to match correctly against what's
  #   already in the DB, do it!
  if already_imported.include? row[index_of_unique_column]
    to_update << row
  else
    to_insert << row
  end
end
```

Then you must build a dynamic `INSERT` *and* a dynamic `UPDATE` for each table involved. Google for `UPDATE` syntax if you need it, and go wild with all your favorite string processing functions!

Going back to the sample code above, note the difference between numeric and string fields. If it is possible that the strings may contain single quotes, you will have to make sure that all the single quotes are escaped. The behavior of `String#gsub` may be surprise you when you try to do this: it assigns a special meaning to `\'`. The best way I have found so far to escape single quotes is: `string.gsub("'") { "\\'" }`. Perhaps other posters know a better way.

If you are inserting dates, make sure they are converted to MySQL's date syntax.

Yes, I know that "roll-your-own" SQL sanitization is very iffy. There may even be security bugs with the above approach; if so, I hope my better-informed peers will set me straight. But the performance gains are just too great to ignore. Again, if this can be done using a prepared query with placeholders, and you know how, please post!

Looking at your code, it looks like you are inserting the data using a stored procedure (`mfmodel.populate`). Even if you do want to use a stored procedure for this, why do you have `dbh.prepare` in the loop? You should be able to move that line outside of `lines.each`.

Comment: @hershey92, Did you try moving the `dbh.prepare` to outside the loop?

Comment: @WayneConrad I am not able to do that please read the last statement of the code block, it indicates the input format and also read the updated question

Comment: @hershey92, Why can't you try moving that statement?  A prepared statement should be prepared just once, and then used repeatedly.  The whole point of a prepared statement is to pay the cost of *preparing* just once, not once per insert or update.

Comment: @WayneConrad that's correct but it doesnt solve the issue as I am repeatedly accessing the database in the `sth.execute statement`

Comment: its taking the same time  more than 7 min

Comment: I've been stuck on this for a real long time, looking for wonderful ideas as I believe ruby must have a way out

Comment: @hershey92, OOP won't help.  The problem is entirely with the database.  You need to find out why it's taking 7 minutes to insert 9000 rows.  That's only 21 transactions per second, which is awful.  Examine your database configuration to see if it's set up for optimum performance.  You may benefit from wrapping your loop in a transaction.  See aos Alex D's still good suggestion of trying a bulk insert.

Comment: dear all I still can't figure how will I create a bulk insert of 7000 lines each like  `106799;-;-;HDFC ARBITRAGE FUND RETAIL PLAN DIVIDEND OPTION;10.352;10.3;10.352;29-Jun-2012` which are supposed to go into 4 different tables.

Comment: finally I need to use Rails and put this script running every 1/2 hr to check for file updates and if it is so, update the database for all file changes.

Comment: @hershey92, I posted some more info for ya... give it a shot and let us know how much the performance of the updated code rocks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try exporting the data as csv and loading it with 'load data infile... replace'. It seems cleaner/easier than trying to construct bulk insert queries.

Comment: Nice suggestion. Do you have specific instructions for loading a CSV file into MySQL?

Comment: ...I have updated the question please have a relook and drop in your suggestions. thnaks